# how to update search results using signalR

Tags: signalr

I've just started learning signalR and I'm trying to implement a search feature.

How would i go about periodically updating a user's search result. My initial idea is to run a timed job via IRegisteredObject to trigger a check from client with search params like so:

```
public class BackgroundTimer : IRegisteredObject
{
    private Timer taskTimer;
    private IHubContext hub;

    public BackgroundTimer()
    {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SearchHub>();

        taskTimer = new Timer(OnTimerElapsed, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender)
    {
        hub.Clients.All.checkForUpdates();
    }
}

public class SearchHub : Hub
{
    public void Search(string searchText)
    {
        string jsonResult = string.Empty;
        //TODO save result to jsonResult
        Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(jsonResult);
    }
}
```

However i can't help but think there are much more efficient ways to accomplish this. Any advice pls

Answer (score 0):

With this code you are just doing what the clients could instead, poll the server each second. Either publish a message on all actions that alter the search result and act on that. Or use SqlDependency.